# Stored procedure does not rename the duplicate column name

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle12c

I am using oracle 12c stored procedures

```
Select inv.*, dtl.* from Inventory inv
left join InventoryDetail dtl ON dtl.INVID = inv.INVID
```

2 columns are of same name in both tables, which is UOM. when I run query in script , it return UOM as well as UOM_1, but in stored procedure, it return only one column UOM , and override the value with  InventoryDetail column.

One solution is that , I use the InventoryDetail value as UOM_DTL. but I want to achieve this using

```
Select inv.*, dtl.* from Inventory inv
left join InventoryDetail dtl
```

Comment: Perhaps don't use asterisks, and instead list the fields out, aliasing the second UOM to whatever you wish.

Comment: @JNevill yeh I can do , as mentioned in above question. any things else using * ?

Comment: Are you sure you want a left outer join without an ON clause to connect the 2 tables? And , like @JNevill wrote, you need to explicitly list the fields, and not use *.

Comment: @RenatoAfonso I basically gave an idea, not wrote a complete query. problem is not on with join , but column name :)

Comment: Ok, so do as @JNevill wrote. There's not much else to do.

Comment: I agree. Not because it was my suggestion and I don't want to budge, but just because there is no other way around this besides renaming the column in the table itself. I always try to be explicit as possible in SQL because relying on the server to determine what you really mean can lead to some oddball results.

Comment: You should never use select * in a production query anyway. It is a SQL antipattern. If you have any joins it will return duplicated data for the join fields and this is inefficient.

Comment: What does UOM mean? I am not familiar with that term.

Comment: @BrianLeach UOM - Unit Of Measure